# Regular Expression returns nothing

Tags: python, regex

I have written the following regular expression to return `everything except alphabets & letters`. However this regular expression **returns nothing**. What can be the regular expression for such case?

**Regex:**

```
r'[^[a-z]+]'
```

Regards

Comment: brackets within brackets.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are messing with the character class `[]`. Here is the correct one(without uppercase):

```
r'[^a-z]+'
```

If you want to match with start and end of string, including Upper case letters.

```
r'^[^a-zA-Z]+$'
```

And here is how you can use it:

```
print re.findall(r'([^a-zA-Z]+)', input_string)
```

`()` means capture the group so that it returns after the matching is performed.

Comment: Can you refer me to some regular expression excersize websites?

Comment: Try with these two. [Here](http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html) and [here](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_reg_expressions.htm).

Comment: And also keep eye on the `Stackoverflow regex tag`. Lot of people are coming up with lot of different problems. [Here it is](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/regex) although you already know it!

Answer (score 2):

This is how the regex engine see's your regex

```
 [^[a-z]+          # Not any of these characters  '[', nor a-z
 ]                 # literal ']'
```

So, as @Sajuj says, just need to remove the outer square brackets `[^a-z]+`